# select 2 - remove items from mulitple select - placeholder only reshows on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 a jquery plugin for selectboxes - http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

one good thing about this is the way to have multiple selects but i am having an issue.

Problem 1 - when you click the dropdown box the placeholder text disappears which is ok as you can see the list but if you click of the list the placeholder will not reshow until you have clicked again.

Problem 2 - if you do actually make 2 or 3 selections and then remove these again when you have removed the last you have to click of the box before the placeholder text comes back.

what i really is for the text to come back as soon as the last element is deleted without the extra click

if you go here http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ and to the Programmatic Access section and use the second drop down you will see the issue.

here is a js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dwhitmarsh/MfJ4B/13/

and here is my code

```
$(function() {  
  $(".select2").select2({ 
        formatSelection: multipleFormatResult,
        dropdownCssClass : 'bigdrop',
        escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
    }).on("change", function(e) {

        //add tooltip when option selected
        var title = $(this).attr("data-placeholder");


        var data=$(this).select2("data");
        if ( checkObject(data) !== true) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("activeLI");
        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("activeLI");
        }

    });

});

var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

function checkObject(obj) {

// null and undefined are empty
if (obj == null) return true;
// Assume if it has a length property with a non-zero value
// that that property is correct.
if (obj.length && obj.length > 0)    return false;
if (obj.length === 0)  return true;

for (var key in obj) {
    if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key))    return false;
}

return true;    
}
function multipleFormatResult(data, container) {    

var markup = data.text;
return markup;
}
```

Comment: I think that how a placeholder has to work. On blur, if textbox is empty show the placeholder  else while focusing it will not be shown.

Comment: can you give me an example please or update the jsfiddle??

Comment: Oh! I was wrong.  Thanks buddy.

Comment: I'm not much familiar with select2 but I've used [chosen.js](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) working good( problem 2).